# WebSphere on VMWare Fusion

Tags: websphere, vmware, vmware-fusion

Any ideas where can I find a free (trial or for educational purposes) WebSphere Application Server image for use with VMWare Fusion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VMware's "Virtual Appliance" pages currently list 4 that contain WebSphere in some form or other](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/cat/0?k=websphere&c=0). I dunno how current/usable/convenient they are, however.